# Postgres Query to filter data based on fieldname and description

Tags: sql, postgresql

**Input**

| fieldname | description |
| --- | --- |
| COST | to populate cost |
| test | To Populate test |
| abc | information about product |

**Output**

| fieldname | description |
| --- | --- |
| abc | information about product |

Need help with query to filter records and not fetch where description! = to populate +fieldname

I have tried this query but its not giving correct result if anyone can help:

replace(replace(lower(regexp_replace(description,'^\s+|\s+$', '', 'g')),' ',''),'_','')!=replace(replace(replace(lower(regexp_replace(concat('to populate',fieldname),'^\s+|\s+$', '', 'g')),' ',''),'_',''),'"','')

Need help with query to filter records and not fetch where description! = to populate +fieldname

Comment: Why are you not selecting the row with `COST_a`.  You want *description! = to populate +fieldname* but `to populate cost` does not equal `to populate COST_a`. So it matches your criteria. Please describe your exact criteria, including case if needed.  Note Postgres uses || as the continuation operator, not +. So `description != to populate || fieldname` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know what the combinations replace functions and regular expression is doing. But is seems a simple select is sufficient. (see [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/3IzluZmm))

```
select fieldname, description
  from input 
 where lower(description)  <>
       'to populate ' || lower(fieldname);
```